# Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll

Tags: command-line, php

When I run the command

`php -v`

this error comes up in ubuntu terminall:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong.  You (or some software you have installed) have enabled something like:

extension=php_mbstring.dll

in the PHP configuration file, and this is wrong as `php_mbstring.dll` is an extension compiled for Windows operating system.

The correct way is to install `php-mbstring` package and let it enable the `mbstring` extension automatically:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

You can then disable/enable the extension by using `phpenmod`/`phpdismod` commands:

```
sudo phpdismod mbstring # disable mbstring extension
sudo phpenmod mbstring # enable mbstring extension again
```

Comment: works for me, using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: works for me, using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 4):

I am Running Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP5.X - PHP7

when I installed php7 i started to get this error with `/usr/lib/php/sessionclean`

to fix this I had to comment out in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` the offending extensions line, which by default were .dll

```
extension=mbstring.dll
```

to

```
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

Comment: This seems likely because you had mbstring enabled in PHP 5 and not when you installed PHP 7 but you kept the same php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warning as above. The solution consisted in commenting the entries as follows in `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` that I previously added (uncommented) while these were not required here.

```
;extension=msql.dll
;extension=msql.so
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
```