# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php, php7

I got error like

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

As @Parto said

I run `php -i | grep ".ini"`

And got result :-

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
com_init_db => 0
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
```

I am using php 7 and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Well, can't say that i've ever seen .dll's being loaded in Ubuntu...

Comment: What does `php -i | grep ".dll"` return when run in terminal? If it returns nothing, run `php -i | grep ".ini"` and include the result in your question.

Comment: @Parto I updated my question.

Comment: First thing to check is, if the DDL file exist somewhere outside the path. So you have to run `find /* -name "php_intl.dll"` make sure you run this as root or user with privilege as some directories have specific permissions being set. Usually, the the php library you're trying to install is part of php5, did you search if PHP7 fully supports it?

Comment: in response to bc2946088's comment back in June, I can confirm that, with a clean ubuntu installation, adding apache, php, mysql and cacti, I am seeing logs which say 'unable to load dynamic library - /usr/lib/php/20121012/php_gd2.dll' - so it looks like either a logging error or apache/php does use this extension. It is weird though.

Answer (score 7):

Run:

```
sudo gedit -H /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

and comment out `extension=php_intl.dll`.

Answer (score 7):

As per [oerdnj's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/776366/368816) there is something wrong with your configuration. You shoul *not* enable the extension in php.ini (e.g. you should not uncomment the line `;extension=php_mbstring.dll`, for instance).

You should install the extension like `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` and let it be automatically activated.

Comment: This helped me, thanks. I found that mine was uncommented in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` but commented out in `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`. Which is why mine only happened at weird times.

Answer (score 7):

Something wrong with your configuration, but if you have root access, just install again the missing extensions. For PHP 7.0:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
sudo apt-get install php7.0-soap
```

Note the version of your Ubuntu could be necessary in some weird cases (you upgraded too much your packages and need to downgrade). Here a example but look at the version installed first!

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl=7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
sudo apt-get install php7.0-soap=7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

Worked for me (not SOAP extension by the way but `intl` and some others)

Answer (score 3):

**Sometime some of extensions are not install**

so you can install it with terminal

run following commands to install that particular extensions

**sudo apt-get install php7.0-extension name**

or

you can install all extension with following command

**sudo apt-get install php7.0-***

Answer (score 1):

I tried with following commands and error gone :

```
nano /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
```

Search for `intl.dll` and `soap.dll` comment this extension

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

First check from where the php.ini file is getting applied for your project.
To check this just save file with below code in root folder with name phpInfo.php

```
<?php echo phpInfo(); ?>
```

Now run the file on browser by typing `http://localhost/file_folder/phpInfo.php` and check for **Loaded Configuration File**. Now open the file in editor and uncomment(remove comma from start) `php_intl`

Don't forget to restart apache.