# How to properly install a PHP extension?

Tags: apache2, php, mint

I want to install some PHP extensions so I can run Laravel projects in the computer. I already uncommented the lines in the **/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini** dir, more precisely:

> extension=php_mbstring.dll
>   extension=php_mysqli.dll
>   extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
>   extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
>   extension=php_pgsql.dll
>   extension=php_xmlrpc.dll

Then I ran `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php-mysqli php-pdo-mysql php-pdo-sqlite php-pgsql php-xmlrpc` and restarted apache service `sudo systemctl restart apache2`. Still, when I run `php --ini` I got:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_sqlite.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pgsql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pgsql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_xmlrpc.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_xmlrpc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I know the problem reducts to only add the `.dll` file to this path but I guess there must be a standard way to do this. Or will I have to download/compile them manually and put there? Thanks in advance.

By the way, I'm on linux mint 18.1 and using PHP 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong. The dll files you have enabled are compiled for Windows.

The correct way is to install php-mbstring package and let it enable the mbstring extension automatically:

sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
You can then disable/enable the extension by using phpenmod/phpdismod commands:

sudo phpdismod mbstring # disable mbstring extension
sudo phpenmod mbstring # enable mbstring extension again

Sources:

[Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776322/startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib-php-20151012-php-mbstring-dll)

Comment: That's strange, when I installed apache/php with apt-get the commented extensions were already with the .dll filetype. Also, I ran `phpenmod` for those extensions but still having the same error at `php --ini`

Comment: You understood that I tried to say, that uncommenting those lines was a MISTAKE. You should only use apt-get install and not the config.